# How to fix redux-form "validate" when rendering an input from a variable in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-admin

So I'm using a custom-built dialog component in react-admin which has a `SimpleForm` inside it. When I try to use input-level `validate` attribute on a `LongTextInput`, it just doesn't work. There is no error in the console or anything like that, but the input just accepts the text as is without validation. I don't seem to understand where I'm going wrong.

In the code that you see below, the inputs in the form that I have to render are conditional based on the props I'm passing from the parent. Hence, creating the form in a variable and then rendering it in the `return()` method.

What I've tried is rendering the inputs directly in the `return()` method without using the variable, but that does not seem to fix the validation problem as well.

Here's the array that defines the validation parameters I want to use -

```js
const validateReason = [required(), minLength(5), maxLength(100)];
```

And I'm using this in the below `render()` method -

```js
render() {
  const props = this.props;
  let renderForm = null;
  if(props.formType === 'reject') {
    renderForm =
    (<SimpleForm
      form="form"
      toolbar={null}>
      <RadioButtonGroupInput onChange={this.handleChoiceChange} source="reason" choices={[
        { id: '1', name: 'Inappropriate' },
        { id: '2', name: 'Abusive' },
        { id: '3', name: 'Not Product Related' },
        { id: '4', name: 'Others' },
      ]} />
      <FormDataConsumer label="Select L2 Category" alwaysOn>
        {({ formData }) => formData.reason === '4' &&
          <LongTextInput
            defaultValue={this.state.reasontext}
            onChange={this.handleReasonChange}
            source="reason_text"
            label={props.title}
            validate={validateReason}
          />
        }
      </FormDataConsumer>
    </SimpleForm>);
  }
  else if(props.formType === 'skip') {
    renderForm =
    (<SimpleForm
      form="form"
      toolbar={null}>
      <LongTextInput
        defaultValue={this.state.reasontext}
        onChange={this.handleReasonChange}
        source="reason_text"
        label={props.title}
        validate={validateReason}
      />
    </SimpleForm>);
  } 
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Dialog
        fullWidth
        open={props.showDialog}
        aria-label={props.title}
      >
        <DialogTitle>{props.title}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          {renderForm}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <SaveButton
            onClick={() => {
              props.handleClose();
              this.handleSaveClick(props.formType);
            }}
            label={props.positiveButtonText}
          />
          <Button onClick={() => {
            this.clearReason();
            props.handleClose();
          }}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

I expect that the `validate` attribute validates my input correctly according to my validation parameters.

Comment: Any luck using validation at the Form level?